# Research question: We measured heart rate variability parameters

Tags: repeated-measures, ancova, medicine

In my research we measured heart rate variability parameters (4 different numerical variables) in 4 different situations in 50 subjects - newborns who were of different age. 
How to control the sample for the age? I would like to see if the situation itself independently of their age effects variability parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the situation itself"* ? Please provide more details about your data, how they were collected and what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: We measured 4 variables - TP, HF, LF, LF/HF in 4 different positions (sleeping on the back, on the stomach ...) for each newborn. We found out that age correlates with variables. Now we would like to show if sleep position impacts the HRV independent
of the age.

Comment: @MancaNolimal if each newborn was measured in each position, then you have balanced design and there's no need to control for age.

Comment: Please include new information as an edit to the Q.

Comment: You can use age as a covariate